# How can I set 200MHz system clock?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to set the system clock this way:

```
`timescale 5 ns/1 ns
```

and then:

```
initial begin 
    forever #0.5 clk = ~clk;
end
```

But, I'm getting the error `Unexpected char '5'`?  Why?  What is the problem with '5'?  10 for instance worked.

Another way that worked but not elegant:

```
 `timescale 1 ns/1 ns
```

and

```
initial begin 
    forever #2.5 clk = ~clk;
end
```

Does someone have a better solution?

Comment: The way that you deem "not elegant" is the way that you should (and everyone does) do it. Except as @toolic says, you're actually going to get a 166MHz clock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with `5 ns` in the `` `timescale `` directive is that it is illegal syntax according to the IEEE Std.  Only 1, 10 and 100 are permitted.

However, there is also a problem with your other code example:

```
`timescale 1 ns/1 ns
forever #2.5 clk = ~clk;
```

That does not produce a 200MHz clock.  It produces a 166MHz clock.  You specified a time precision of 1ns, which means that fractional delays will be rounded.  In this case. 2.5 is rounded up to 3, which means you end up with a period of 6ns, not 5ns.  You can see this by adding the following code to your testbench:

```
initial $monitor($realtime, "\tclk=%b", clk);
```

Then you will see the period of `clk` is 6ns:

```
0   clk=0
3   clk=1
6   clk=0
9   clk=1
12  clk=0
15  clk=1
```

One way to achieve a 200MHz clock is to use a precision of 100ps:

```
`timescale 1 ns / 100 ps
forever #2.5 clk = ~clk;
```

Answer (score 3):

From IEEE 1800-2017, section 22.7:

> The time_unit argument specifies the unit of measurement for times and
>   delays. The time_precision argument specifies how delay values are
>   rounded before being used in simulation. The time_precision argument
>   shall be at least as precise as the time_unit argument; it cannot
>   specify a longer unit of time than time_unit.
>   **The integers in these arguments specify an order of magnitude for the
>   size of the value; the valid integers are 1, 10, and 100.**

I think you are misunderstanding what the timescale directive is for. It is for specifying the *time unit* and *time precision* of your simulation, not for specifying your clock period.

---

By the way: you can download IEEE 1800-2017 for free from the IEEE. (Accelera pays.) I recommend you do. It's quite readable.